# Pong game with 8x8 matrix LED display in Arduino

Tags: beginner, arduino

I was working on programming an 8x8 matrix LED display. In particular, I am trying to make a basic version of Pong, controlled by two switches, one switch for each paddle.

- A ball is generated and moves to one paddle and is reflected upon collision with a paddle.
- If the ball fails to collide with a paddle on the left or right side, the ball is reset to the center of the field.
- If the ball collides with the floor or ceiling, it rebounds to the left or right side.

This game will be more of an enhancement to an encompassing display I will be doing.

Constructive criticism would be of great service, to help a beginner out.

Here is the code I've done so far (done today):

```
int column[] = {2, 7, 19, 5, 10, 18, 11, 16};                            // Anode pins in order they represent as column
int row[] = {6, 14, 15, 3, 17, 4, 8, 9};                              // Cathode pins in order they represent as row

//button PINs
const int LEFT_BUTTON = 13;
const int RIGHT_BUTTON = 12;

int leftPad[] = {0,0,128,128,128,0,0,0};
int rightPad[] = {0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0};
int ball[] = {0,0,0,16,0,0,0,0};

//Global variables
int left = 1;
int right = -1;
int rdir;                           //random direction for ball
int deltaCo = 0;                           //Change in ball 'co-ordinate'
int ballPosition;                           //Determines x-position of ball

int leftCounter = 0;                           //Determinor for change in left paddle direction
int rightCounter = 0;                           //Determinor for change in right paddle direction
unsigned long firstLeftMillis = 0; 
unsigned long lastLeftMillis = 0;
unsigned long firstRightMillis = 0; 
unsigned long lastRightMillis = 0;
                                                         //Reference variables for array indexes
int leftCo = 2; 
int rightCo = 2;
int ballCo = 3;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);                          //Generic: Sets the data rate in bauds for serial data transmission    
  randomSeed(analogRead(0));                          //Initializes the pseudo-random number generator with random analogue input

  for (int next = 0; next < 8; next++)                          // sets all I/O used as outputs
  {
    pinMode(column[next], OUTPUT);
    pinMode(row[next], OUTPUT);
  }

  pinMode(LEFT_BUTTON, INPUT);                          //Sets both button I/O as inputs
  pinMode(RIGHT_BUTTON, INPUT);

  int determinant = random(1,10);                          //Randomy determine ball y-position and initial ball direction

  ballPosition = random(3,5);                        

  if (determinant % 2 == 0)
  {
    rdir = 1;
  }
  else
  {
    rdir = -1;
  }
}

void ClearArray(int toClear[])                          //Clears array; sets all array indexes to 0
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
    toClear[i] = 0;
  }
}

void loop() {                          //Runs pong on the matrix
 int rightButton = digitalRead(RIGHT_BUTTON);                          //Get states of both buttons
 int leftButton = digitalRead(LEFT_BUTTON);

  if (leftButton == HIGH)                          //For when the left button is pressed
  { 
    firstLeftMillis = millis();                          //Sets time in milliseconds from start
    if ((leftPad[0] == 128) || (leftPad[7] == 128))                        //If the paddle reaches the ends of the screen, direction is flipped
    {
      left *= -1;
    }

    leftCo += left;                          //Changes the reference vertical coordinate for the left paddle
    ClearArray(leftPad);                          //Clears the paddle
    leftPad[leftCo] = 128;                          //'Turns on' on the display for the paddle with appropriate coordinates
    leftPad[leftCo + 1] = 128;
    leftPad[leftCo + 2] = 128;
  }
  else if ((leftPad[0] == 0) && (leftPad[7] == 0))                           //Applies once button is released and if the paddle does not touch the ends                         
  {
    lastLeftMillis = millis();                          //Sets time in milliseconds from start

    if (lastLeftMillis - firstLeftMillis < 500)                           //If time pressed is within a sufficiently short timeframe, increments the counter
    {
      leftCounter++;
    }

    if (leftCounter % 2 == 0)                           //If counter is odd, flips the direction; in effect, every two 'rapid button clicks' changes the direction fo the paddle
    {
      left *= -1;
    }

    firstLeftMillis = lastLeftMillis;                          //Make sure you update the time
  }

  if (rightButton == HIGH)                          //For when the right button is pressed
  {
    firstRightMillis = millis();                          //Same shebang; update the time

    if ((rightPad[0] == 1) || (rightPad[7] == 1))                          //If the paddle reaches the ends of the screen vertically within the column, flip direction
    {
      right *= -1;
    }

    rightCo += right;                          //Change the vertical reference coordinate of the right paddle
    ClearArray(rightPad);                          //Clears the array for the right paddle
    rightPad[rightCo] = 1;                          //'Turns on' the paddle with appropriate coordinates
    rightPad[rightCo + 1] = 1;
    rightPad[rightCo + 2] = 1;
  } 
  else if ((rightPad[0] == 0) && (rightPad[7] == 0))                           //Applies once button is released and if the paddle does not touch the ends    
  {
    lastRightMillis = millis();                           //Update time

    if (lastRightMillis - firstRightMillis < 500)                           //Increments counter if button is pressed and released in quick succession
    {
      rightCounter++;
    }

    if (rightCounter % 2 == 0)                           //If the right counter is even, flip the direction of the paddle
    {
      right *= -1;
    }

    firstRightMillis = lastRightMillis;                           //Updates the time
  }

  if (ball[ballCo] == 64)                           //Applies when the ball occupies a column adjacent to the column for the left paddle
  {
    if (leftPad[ballCo] != 0)                           //If the paddle is 'on' in a cell horizontally adjacent to the ball, flip direction of ball
    {
      rdir *= -1;

      if (ballCo == leftCo)                           //Determines vertical movement of ball if ball comes into contact with edge of paddle; initially no vertical movement
      {
        deltaCo = 1;
      }
      else if (ballCo == leftCo - 2)
      {
        deltaCo = -1;
      }
      else if (ballCo == leftCo + 2)
      {
        deltaCo = 1;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      deltaCo = 0;                           //Otherwise, reset ball as it has been lost by the left paddle
      ballCo = random(2,4);
      ballPosition = 3;
    }
  }
  else if (ball[ballCo] == 2)                           //Applies when the ball occupies a column adjacent to the column for the right paddle
  {
    if (rightPad[ballCo] != 0)                           //If the paddle is 'on' in a cell horizontally adjacent to the ball, flip direction of ball
    {
      rdir *= -1;

      if (ballCo == rightCo)                           //Determines vertical movement of ball if ball comes into contact with edge of paddle; initially no vertical movement
      {
        deltaCo = -1;
      }
      else if (ballCo == rightCo - 2)
      {
        deltaCo = 1;
      }
      else if (ballCo == rightCo + 2)
      {
        deltaCo = -1;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      deltaCo = 0;                           //Otherwise, reset ball as it has been lost by the right paddle
      ballCo = random(2,4);
      ballPosition = 5;
    }
  }

  if ((ballCo == 0) || (ballCo == 7))                           //If the ball touches the cieling or floor of the display, reverses the vertical movement of the ball
  {
    deltaCo *= -1;
  }

  ballPosition += rdir;                           //Changes ball horizontal position
  ballCo += deltaCo;                           //Changes ball vertical position; initially 0
  ClearArray(ball);                           //Clears ball array
  ball[ballCo] = pow(2, ballPosition) + 0.5;                           //Determines ball horizontal coordinate in relation to vertical coordinate

  scanAll(leftPad, rightPad, ball);                           //Displays the left paddle, right paddle and ball
}

void scanAll(int firstArray[], int secondArray[], int thirdArray[])                                 
{
  turnOffAllcolumn();
  unsigned long startTime = millis();

  do {
    for (int currentRow = 0; currentRow < 8; currentRow++)
    {
      outputRow(firstArray[currentRow], currentRow);    //increments bits for scan of row.
      outputRow(secondArray[currentRow], currentRow);
      outputRow(thirdArray[currentRow], currentRow);
    }
  } while (millis() - startTime < 500);                         //delay for how long character is shown.
}

void outputRow(int cols, int curRow)                            //increments bits for scan of row.
{
  digitalWrite(row[curRow], HIGH);                              //turns on current row

  for (int currentColumn = 0; currentColumn < 8; currentColumn++)
  {
    boolean isAlive = bitRead(cols, currentColumn);           //determine if current column is a 1 or 0
    if (isAlive)
    {
      digitalWrite(column[currentColumn], LOW);             //if column was a 1 - turns it on and then off again.
      digitalWrite(column[currentColumn], HIGH);
    }
  }
  digitalWrite(row[curRow], LOW);                             //shuts off current row
}

void turnOffAllcolumn()
{
  for (int currentColumn = 0; currentColumn < 8; currentColumn++)
  {
    digitalWrite(column[currentColumn], HIGH);                // reset column to off
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Code Review! Is your code working as intended or is there some issue left?

Comment: It is working as intended, but could perhaps use some tweaking/optimization.